# When any other sibling has the class .selected in it, do not slide up the accordion of that specific sibling

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jQuery code to handle when an .item div is clicked to slide down the accordion, and slide up the already opened .item div accordion if any exists:

```
$(".item").on("click", function() { 
 $(".itemchildren:visible").slideUp(100);   
  if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {         
    $(this).next().slideDown(100);
   } 
});
```

I also have this which adds the .selected class when an .itemchildren-item div in the accordion of an .item div is clicked and removes the .active class when an .itemchildren-item div in another .item div is clicked:

```
$('.itemchildren-item').click(function() {
    var $thisitem = $(this);
    var $ancestor = $thisitem.parents('.itemchildren').prev();
    var $acs = $(".item");
    $acs.each(function( index, value ){
    $acs.eq(index).removeClass('selected');
    });
        $ancestor.addClass('selected');
});
```

I want a jQuery code that if an .item div has the .selected class, not to close the accordion of that .selected div, and only close it if another .item div gets the .selected class.

HTML Structure of the accordion:

```
<!--first item (has selected class by default)-->
<div class="flex item expand selected">
    <div class="flex icon">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="flex text">
        Dashboard
    </div>
</div>

<!--accordion content of first item-->
<div class="flex itemchildren">
    <a class="flex itemchildren-item">
        <div class="text">
            Home
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="flex itemchildren-item">
        <div class="text">
            Contact
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<!--Second item-->
<div class="flex item expand">
    <div class="flex icon">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="flex text">
        Menus
    </div>
</div>

<!--accordion of second item-->
<div class="flex itemchildren">
    <a class="flex itemchildren-item">
        <div class="text">
            All Menus
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="flex itemchildren-item">
        <div class="text">
            Add New Menu
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added and each function and checked for the 'selected' class is on the item, so it will only fires the slideUp() if the class is not set. I have created the my_slideup function to make it cleaner.

```js
$(".item").each(function(){ 
    $(this).on("click", function() {
           
        //slides up function for all children
        my_slideUp();
        //if it hasn't got the selected class slidedown
        if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')){
             if ($(this).children('.itemchildren').is(':visible')){  
                 $(this).children('.itemchildren').slideUp(100);
             } else {
                 $(this).children('.itemchildren').slideDown(100);
             }   
         } 
    });
});

//my_slideup function
function my_slideUp(){
  $(".item").each(function(){
     if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')){ 
       $(this).children('.itemchildren').slideUp(100);
     }
  });
}
//adding selected class to parent
$('.itemchildren-item').on('click',function() {
     //remove all selected classes first
     $(".item").removeClass('selected'); 
     $(this).parent().parent().addClass('selected'); 
});
```

```css
.item {
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #CCC;
   width: 100%;
}
.itemchildren {
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #CCC;
   background: #fefefe;
   width: 100%;
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--first item (has selected class by default)-->
<div class="flex item expand">
  <div class="flex icon">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="flex text">
        Dashboard
  </div>
  <!--accordion content of first item-->
  <div class="flex itemchildren">
      <a class="flex itemchildren-item">
          <div class="text">
              Home
          </div>
      </a>
      <a class="flex itemchildren-item">
          <div class="text">
              Contact
          </div>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Second item-->
<div class="flex item expand">
    <div class="flex icon">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="flex text">
        Menus
    </div>


    <!--accordion of second item-->
    <div class="flex itemchildren">
        <a class="flex itemchildren-item">
            <div class="text">
                All Menus
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="flex itemchildren-item">
            <div class="text">
                Add New Menu
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are kinda close, but what I need is for example if "Dashboard" has the .selected and you click on "Menus", do not close the accordion of "Dashboard" until an item inside the "Menus" accordion is selected. And this should happen ONLY TO ITEMS THAT HAVE THE .SELECTED CLASS, if the item doesn't have it, the accordion should close when another item is selected. Also when the snippet runs the accordions are already open for some reason :(

Comment: just a quick question, is there any reason why the children are in a separate div?

Comment: Couldn't seem to make it work otherwise... I'm kinda new to jQuery... If I put the .itemchildren inside the .item div they wouldn't work... =/

Comment: Code update above, i have put the children inside the parent element, makes thing a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last thing! When the .selected item's accordion is down, and you open another one, you can't close it if you click again on the non-.selected div!

Comment: Added the .is(':visible') back in to check if the children where visible and changed the .parents() to parent().parent() as it was targeting all parent elements

Comment: I also have something that when you click on an .itemchildren-item to give it the class .active, can we do something that if the .itemchildren-item already has the .active class, not to remove it if clicked again, and only remove it if clicked on a sibling .itemchildren-item or an .itemchildren-item on another .item? Also, I want to make an .item that has no children in it, and when you click on it, make the same actions as if you clicked on an .itemchildren-item to the single .item.. Sorry for asking this much but you giving me these examples is really helping me figure out some other things!